# Can I run a Java 32-bit application on a 64bit system

Tags: 64-bit, java

Natty 64-bit is installed. iMindmap 5 a Java 32 program will not run correctly.

Is installing 32-bit Java a possible solution?

Comment: Yes it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible - obviously you will need to manually flip between 64bit or 32bit Java depending upon the application you will be using:

Using the ‘Ubuntu Software Center’ just search for ‘Java 32′ and install (if not installed) the 32-bit JRE. Currently it is called ‘ia32-sun-java6-bin’.

Next open your terminal window and and run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java.
```

This will you give you various versions of Java running on your Ubuntu machine. Simply select the 32-bit instance of the JRE you prefer and press enter.

Next we need to check that we have the right version of Java running. Do this by entering `java -version` in the terminal window.

You should see similar output as:

```
java version “1.6.0_07″
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_07-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 10.0-b23, mixed mode)
```

1. Linked Question: ['Permission denied' while installing 32-bit Java (JDK/JRE) on 64-bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24726/installing-32-bit-java-jdk-jre-on-64-bit-ubuntu-server)

[source 1](http://www.improvateit.com/blog/2010/10/running-32-bit-java-on-64-bit-ubuntu/)
[source 2](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/15628)

Comment: or use `update-java-alternatives` which is a shortcut, specifically for java.

Comment: Can we run 2 application at a time when 1 uses 64-bit Java and another uses 32-bit Java?