# Can I install a 32-bit Java in addition to a 64-bit version?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, java, 32-bit

For normal development I'm using the 64-bit VM which comes when I install the Java development kit (OpenJDK) with the package manager.

But there are some Java applications (containing native libraries, I suppose) which don't work on a 64 bit Java VM. (Looks like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is such a candidate - in version 4.0.1 and 4.5 beta 1, it fails with a segmentation fault if run in a 64 bit VM.)

I tried to install the i386-version of openjdk-6-jre in addition to the 64-bit one, but this is refused by aptitude (saying that it conflicts with the existing 64-bit version). The same happens if I try to install openjdk-jre-7 in the 32-bit version.

An answer to [Can I run a Java 32-bit application on a 64bit system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59950/can-i-run-a-java-32-bit-application-on-a-64bit-system) proposed to install `ia32-sun-java6-bin`, but there is no package with this name (or anything with `ia32` and Java).

What could I do here to run SoapUI without switching my whole system Java installation to 32 bit?

Comment: I actually managed to run soapUI with the 64-bit version by editing the shell script to pass some different parameter. I'll have to look up What exactly I did.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/111947/running-32-bit-firefox-with-sun-jre-in-64-bit-ubuntu/203006#203006 for installing both 64 bit and 32 bit java from the repositories. You can change the default too.

Answer (score 4):

It's super easy to have multiple versions of Java installed. Somewhat harder (read: tedious) is switching between versions at a whim.

## tldr

1. apt-get one
2. untar the other
3. export paths depending which one you want

## apt-get one version

Decide which version you'll mostly be using. Or decide which one you want to have automatic updates. Or flip a coin, whatever. You don't even have to use `apt-get`; just manually maintain both packages on your system (see next heading).

The point is: it's easier to use Ubuntu's package manager to maintain exactly one version of a package like java. You're gonna take care of the rest.

## untar the other

Download a jdk tarball. Extract it to `/opt`.

## switch between them

I let the package manager handle my primary install. I export some vars for the other one when I need it. I work on the command line a lot, so it's an okay solution for me. I bother with:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Also, I symlink `jdk/` -> `jdk1.6.0_3/` because I'm lazy and don't like reconfiguring my .bashrc and other scripts every incremental jdk upgrade.

Environment variables you might care about:

```
JAVA_LIBDIR
JNI_LIBDIR
JAVAJNI_LIBDIR
JVM_ROOT
JAVA_HOME
PATH
```

Comment: Couldn't you just as well get the `.deb` for the other architecture instead of the tarball?

Comment: @0xC0000022L The idea is that you contain each version to its own directory. If you can do that with a deb, great!

Answer (score 2):

Installation

First, [download](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) the latest 32 bit JDK (not JRE) from Sun. At the time this was jdk-6u7-linux-i586.bin for me.

Install java-package:

```
sudo apt-get install java-package
```

Now use java-package to build a .deb package from the binary you downloaded. You have to trick it into building the 32 bit package:

```
DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=i486-linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH=i386 fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-6u7-linux-i586.bin
```

This should generate a .deb package. For some reason the package name has the _amd64 suffix. Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i sun-j2sdk1.6_1.6.0+update7_amd64.deb
```

Use update-alternatives to select the new JDK. It was installed at /usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun for me.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

If you run java -version you should see the correct version:

```
java version "1.6.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_07-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 10.0-b23, mixed mode)
```

32 bit Eclipse

I had to reinstall the 32 bit version of Eclipse (since SWT contains native code). I also had to delete my ~/.eclipse directory or Eclipse wouldn’t start (this requires reinstalling new versions of any plugins). Finally, add the new JRE in Java->Installed JREs using the install location (/usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun) and select it as the default.

[ref](http://java.dzone.com/tips/32-bit-jdk-a-64-bit-ubuntu-sys)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this ... although I don't want the 32-bit one be the default, only use it for the few programs who don't work with 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can only install ia32-libs

```
 apt-get install ia32-libs
```

unzip the x86 jre

http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=63983

and add to PATH if you want to.

Comment: installing `ia32-libs` is not the recommended method on ubuntu-11.10 onward. http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package