# How to install Juniper on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, vpn

How to install Juniper on ubuntu 16.04x64?

I install 32bit java:

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /home/romanovi/opt/jdk1.8.0_91-i386/bin/java     2         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java    1080      manual mode
* 4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1         manual mode
```

What should I do next?

Comment: seems to be a answered in http://askubuntu.com/a/450583/555486 and http://askubuntu.com/a/152724/555486