# How to prevent Juniper Network Connect breaking DNS resolutions

Tags: networking, vpn, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

Juniper Network Connect has been an issue on 64bit Linux for quite sometime. I have found 2 solutions to the Java issue ([Could anyone provide a step by step for getting juniper netconnect and citrix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130473/could-anyone-provide-a-step-by-step-for-getting-juniper-netconnect-and-citrix) and  [Running 32-bit Firefox with sun-jre in 64-bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111947/running-32-bit-firefox-with-sun-jre-in-64-bit-ubuntu)) but now I am struggling with a new issue.

Network Connect makes changes directly to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. This causes issues with the newer way that Ubuntu does DNS resolutions which is to point DNS to the local resolver/cacher: `dnsmasq`. Once NC disconnects and you change networks, e.g. go from office to home, then DNS stops working correctly.

What happens is that NC deletes the `/etc/resolv.conf` file which is actually symlinked to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. What's worse is that NC actually deletes the original file not the link. So when you try to restore the file with:

```
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

It fails as `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` is now gone. Re-installing `resolvconf` does not fix it and neither does running `resolvconf`.

So the best way I have found so far is to first backup `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` to another location. After you disconnect NC I then run a script that removes `/etc/resolv.conf`, replaces the deleted  `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and then links it back to `/etc` again.

**Does anyone know a way to avoid this or do I pretty much have he best "fix" in place already? Any way to prevent NC from breaking it in the first place?**

Comment: Not just 64 bit. I have the same issue on 32 bit 12.04.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/224966/how-do-i-get-resolvconf-to-regenerate-resolv-conf-after-i-change-etc-network-in

Answer (score 4):

**First:** clicking the **Sign Out** button in the **Network Connect** window (the window that shows the VPN IP while connected) and

**Then** clicking on the **Sign Out** button in the **logged-in web page** avoids this problem.

Please indicate in comment if this works or not.

Thanks

Comment: I found this to be true as well. It's really stupid to have to click 2 log out buttons, but this works.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I agree this is stupid. However, I think two clicks is far better than typing 30 or more characters on the terminal afterwords.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to fix the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink is to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

and answer YES to prepare resolv.conf for dynamic updates.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that you do not need to reinstall the package. Just restarting resolvconf should fix the problem:

```
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

If that does not happen to work, in addition you can try restarting the network service which will try to write a new set of values to /etc/resolv.conf

```
sudo service network restart
```

Answer (score 1):

After Network Connect has been stopped it suffices to do the following.

```
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u  # Regenerate /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

You don't need to back up /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf beforehand.