# Internet (wifi and ethernet) in 12.04 after some time just stops working

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection

So I have 12.04 on a HP Pavilion g series laptop.

12.04 works fine on my computer.

Then several weeks ago, my laptop would no longer connect to the internet. My tablet connects fine. I booted ubuntu on my USB and it works fine. Something seems to be wrong "within" Ubuntu.

I have now reinstalled ubuntu 4 times. After varying amounts of time the same problem reoccurs (and I have stopped updating any software in case this is the problem).

I use Cisco Anyconnect and Real VNC to log into a server somewhere else (they are the only programs I could imagine causing any problems).

Comment: Please clarify the question by adding more information. When "Internet stops working" does the network manager still say that you are connected? What does the connection properties show? What does the file /etc/resolv.conf show? If answers to both are yes, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/156154/how-to-prevent-juniper-network-connect-breaking-dns-resolutions for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04 and later `/etc/resolv.conf` should be a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. The latter is generated dynamically by the resolvconf utility. Interface configurers are supposed to be resolvconf-aware.

Third-party interface configurers and in particular third-party VPN interface configurers are frequently not resolvconf-aware and write to /etc/resolv.conf directly, and don't restore the symbolic link afterwards. They leave the machine with a misconfigured resolver. Please check for this problem.

If you have this problem then you may be able to fix it by running

```
dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```