# java plugin is not working

Tags: firefox, java, google-chrome

I want to run following website in chrome/firefox in my ubuntu : `http://bikecad.ca/quickapplet`

which shows following message:
[image: which shows following me]

However i have already followed [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155852/installing-chrome-java-plugin)

but its not working.

Help me to deal with this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Oracle JDK 8 using this set of commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then restart `firefox/chrome`