# dpkg-genchanges: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; cannot distribute

Tags: java, 32-bit

I am trying to install 32-bit Java alongside 64-bit Java where I can switch between them.  The most promising way I have found to install 32-bit Java 8 is to build a deb package with make-jpkg as described in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110852/can-i-install-a-32-bit-java-in-addition-to-a-64-bit-version).  But I am getting the following error.  I haven't found anything quite like it online to help in troubleshooting, so I am looking for advice on what I can do here.

```
user@host ~/Downloads $ DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=i486-linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH=i386 fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-8u161-linux-i586.tar.gz 
Creating temporary directory: /tmp/make-jpkg.hiCayyvkiE
Loading plugins: /usr/share/java-package/common.sh /usr/share/java-package/javase.sh /usr/share/java-package/jdk-doc.sh /usr/share/java-package/oracle-jdk-doc.sh /usr/share/java-package/oracle-jdk.sh /usr/share/java-package/oracle-jre.sh /usr/share/java-package/oracle-server-jre.sh

Detected Debian build architecture: i386
Detected Debian GNU type: i486-linux-gnu

Detected product:
    Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK)
    Standard Edition, Version 8 Update 161
    Oracle(TM)
Is this correct [Y/n]: y

Checking free diskspace: done.

In the next step, the binary file will be extracted. Probably a
license agreement will be displayed. Please read this agreement
carefully. If you do not agree to the displayed license terms, the
package will not be built.

Press [Return] to continue: 



Testing extracted archive... okay.

Create debian package:
dpkg-buildpackage: source package oracle-java8-jdk
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 8u161
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Debian Java Maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build package
 debian/rules clean
dh clean
 debian/rules build
dh build
 debian/rules binary
dh binary
 dpkg-genchanges -b >../oracle-java8-jdk_8u161_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; cannot distribute
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genchanges gave error exit status 2

Aborted (-us).

Removing temporary directory: done
```